# SQL: mean of appearances in two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the correlation within two time series stored into a PostgreSQL database in the following way:

| first_object_identifier | second_object_identifier | correlation_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1.0 |
| A | C | 0.9 |
| A | D | 0.8 |
| B | C | 0.7 |
| B | D | 0.6 |
| C | D | 0.5 |

And I would like to get the mean of the correlations where each identifier appears (in one of the both columns of identifiers):

| object_identifier | mean_correlation |
| --- | --- |
| A | mean_A |
| B | mean_B |
| C | mean_C |
| D | mean_D |

Where:

```
mean_A = (AB + AC + AD) / 3 = (1.0 + 0.9 + 0.8) / 3 = 0.9
mean_B = (AB + BC + BD) / 3 = (1.0 + 0.7 + 0.6) / 3 = 0.766
mean_C = (AC + BC + CD) / 3 = (0.9 + 0.7 + 0.5) / 3 = 0.7
mean_D = (AD + BD + CD) / 3 = (0.8 + 0.6 + 0.5) / 3 = 0.633
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

One reasonable, database independent solution is `union all`:

```
select 'A', avg(correlation_value)
from t
where 'A' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier)
union all
select 'B', avg(correlation_value)
from t
where ' ' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier)
union all
select 'C', avg(correlation_value)
from t
where 'C' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier)
union all
select 'D', avg(correlation_value)
from t
where 'D' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier);
```

Or, if you want the results in columns instead of rows:

```
select avg(case when 'A' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier) then correlation_value end),
       avg(case when 'B' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier) then correlation_value end),
       avg(case when 'C' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier) then correlation_value end),
       avg(case when 'D' in (first_object_identifier, second_object_identifier) then correlation_value end)
from t;
```

EDIT:

You can generalize the first method using:

```
select o.id, avg(correlation_value)
from ((select first_object_identifier as id from t
      ) union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select second_object_identifier from t
      )
     ) o left join
     t
     on o.id in (o.first_object_identifier, o.second_object_identifier)
group by o.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is there any more generic way to do it? For example, if I have hundred different identifiers

Comment: @PabloS. . . . It is actually easily generalizable.